# Array empty when i call for index 0 but not when i print the whole array PHP

Tags: php

So when i use this:

```
print_r($events->getLocation($event['event_name']));
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => Düsseldorf, Germany
        )
)
```

But when i use this:

```
print_r($events->getLocation($event['event_name'][0]));
```

It returns this:

```
Array
(
)
```

`$event` is an array from a `foreach` and `$events` is my class.

Comment: Have a look at the getLocation() method. PHP doesn't lie. It seems somehow your method returns an empty array. That does not mean that the array you provide as argument is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print_r($events->getLocation($event['event_name'])[0]);
```

Comment: You can only guess that. If the method behaves faulty this won't fix it at all.

Comment: thank you.... i feel bloody stupid now. ill select your answer as correct as soon as the site will let me

Comment: @devnull It's pretty clear from the question that this is the right answer.

Comment: or we can use:
$location = $events->getLocation($event['event_name']);
print_r($location[0]);
=> it will clear

Comment: A few lines of explanation wouldn't hurt, would they?